# batch file copy files from multiple sources and rename it by removing last 33 characters

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

i have batch file which need to copy 3 last modified files from 3 different sources and need to rename it by removing last 33 characters.

i made it in 2 files but from som reason when i put both codes together its not working...

my code :

```
@echo off

set folderpath=C:\Users\tzahi.k\Desktop\testSource\des

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir  /b /od "C:\Users\tzahi.k\Desktop\testSource\source\*.txt"') do set Youngest=%%a

xcopy /y "C:\Users\tzahi.k\Desktop\testSource\source\%Youngest%" %folderpath%


for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir  /b /od "C:\Users\tzahi.k\Desktop\testSource\source2\*.txt"') do set Youngest=%%a

xcopy /y "C:\Users\tzahi.k\Desktop\testSource\source2\%Youngest%" %folderpath%

cd %folderpath%
for /f %%a in ('dir /b "%folderpath%\*.txt"') do (
   set "fname=%%~na"
   ren "%%a" "!fname:~0,-33!.txt"
)


pause
```

when i split the code in 2 files it works but i want it in one...
any suggestion?

Comment: enable delayed expansion and try , and add some echo statements  in between your code to check if variables are getting updated correctly.

Comment: thanks...works good

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? please provide a detailed description by [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37693963/edit)ing your post; in general, I recommend to put *all* file/dir. paths in between `""` (see `xcopy`'s destination) and use the quoted `set` syntax `set "VAR=Value"`...

Answer (score 0):

i use 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
and it works